# Do while loops? (JAVA)

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I'm doing a program that's essentially a movie quiz, reading the movie titles/release dates/genre/gross amt from a text file which I got working fine, the problem is getting this do while loop to work correctly by quitting at any time the user enters no when prompted at both times (after each question, and at the very end)
Any advice/tips are greatly appreciated!

Here's what I have:

```
private static void movieQuiz (Movies[] movieRecord){

    int score = 0; 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    String userChoice;

    System.out.println("You have selected the Movie Quiz! The instructions"
            + " are as follows: The program will output \nthe title of one of "
            + "the highest grossing films of all time, your job is "
            + "to guess which year \nit was released. A point will be added "
            + "to your score for each correct answer, and your total \npoints will"
            + " display at the end or until you want to give up. Have fun and"
            + " good luck!\n");
    int test = 0;
    loadMovies(movieRecord);
    System.out.println("Are you ready to begin?");
    userChoice = keyboard.next();

    //do this if they want to run it again
    do {
      for (int count = 0; count <= movieRecord.length-1; count++) {
        System.out.println("Movie #" + (test+1) + ": " + movieRecord[count].movieTitle);
        System.out.println("Guess the year");
        int guess = keyboard.nextInt();

          if (guess == movieRecord[count].releaseYear){
            System.out.println("DING DING DING! (+1) \n" );
            score++;
          }

          else {
            System.out.println("Wrong (+0) \n");
          }

          System.out.println("Continue? (Currently on #" + (1 + test) + " out of "
          + movieRecord.length + ")");
          userChoice = keyboard.next();

          test++;

      }
    }   while (userChoice.charAt(0) == 'y');

      //display if they type 'no' at any time, ending the program
      System.out.println("Total Score is: " + score + " out of " + movieRecord.length);
        System.out.println("AGAIN? yes/no?");
        userChoice = keyboard.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a [break](http://www.java-examples.com/break-statement)!!!!

You need to learn about break in Java and implement that in your code.

Comment: Don't get me wrong I am completely aware of the break statement, but for the reason that is currently escaping me, my professor warned us AGAINST using break statements in general and try to find other alternatives. Regardless, I got it to work thank you to you all

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this ?

```
     int score = 0; 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        String userChoice;

        System.out.println("You have selected the Movie Quiz! The instructions"
                + " are as follows: The program will output \nthe title of one of "
                + "the highest grossing films of all time, your job is "
                + "to guess which year \nit was released. A point will be added "
                + "to your score for each correct answer, and your total \npoints will"
                + " display at the end or until you want to give up. Have fun and"
                + " good luck!\n");
        int test = 0;
        loadMovies(movieRecord);
        System.out.println("Are you ready to begin?");
        userChoice = keyboard.next();

        //do this if they want to run it again
        do {
          for (int count = 0; count <= movieRecord.length-1; count++) {
            System.out.println("Movie #" + (test+1) + ": " + movieRecord[count].movieTitle);
            System.out.println("Guess the year");
            int guess = keyboard.nextInt();

              if (guess == movieRecord[count].releaseYear){
                System.out.println("DING DING DING! (+1) \n" );
                score++;
              }

              else {
                System.out.println("Wrong (+0) \n");
              }

              System.out.println("Continue? (Currently on #" + (1 + test) + " out of "
              + movieRecord.length + ")");
              userChoice = keyboard.next();

              if(userChoice.charAt(0) == 'n'){
              //display if they type 'no' at any time, ending the program
              System.out.println("Total Score is: " + score + " out of " + movieRecord.length);
                System.out.println("AGAIN? yes/no?");
                userChoice = keyboard.next();
                if (userChoice.charAt(0) == 'n')
                    break;
              }

              test++;

          }
        }   while (userChoice.charAt(0) == 'y');

    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain to a passer-by what the *difference* between your code and the original is? At a glance, I can only see you've taken out the last few statements.

Comment: I actually placed the last few statements in inside the while loop (near the end) and added a break if the user decides to definitely stop the execution. These statements are only executed if the user asks for leaving the game after a question at first.

Comment: Try this in a main : 

  Scanner k = new Scanner (System.in);
  String u;
  System.out.println("ready?");
  u = k.next();
  do {
  for (int count = 0; count <= 5; count++) {
    System.out.println("gess number");
    k.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Continue?");
    u = k.next();
    if(u.charAt(0) == 'n'){
         System.out.println("AGAIN? yes/no?");
         u = k.next();
         if (u.charAt(0) == 'n')
             break;
           }
          }
        }   while (u.charAt(0) == 'y');
    }

Comment: D. Urvoy, thank you very much for the assistance, it definitely works now.. looks like a break statement was really what was needed.